# Find file from name and array of extensions

Tags: php, arrays, file, file-extension

This works for me now:

```
if (file_exists($filename . '.mp4')) {
    $filepath = "$filename.mp4";
} elseif (file_exists($filename . '.avi')) {
    $filepath = "$filename.avi";
} elseif (file_exists($filename . '.mkv')) {
    $filepath = "$filename.mkv";
}
```

I am looking for an easier way to filter a list of file extensions from an array.

Comment: The question is, do you want to find the first existing file, or all existing files?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$extensions = ['mp4', 'avi', 'mkv'];     

foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $current = $filename . '.' . $extension;

    if (file_exists($current)) {
        $filepath = $current;

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear from your question whether you want to find the *first* existing file or *all* existing files, here's a solution for finding all of them:

```
$extensions = ['mp4', 'avi', 'mkv'];     

$filepaths = array_filter(
    array_map(
        function ($extension) use ($filename) {
            return $filename . '.' . $extension;
        }, 
        $extensions
    ),
    function ($filepath) {
        return file_exists($filepath);
    }
);
```

Alternatively with a `foreach` loop:

```
$extensions = ['mp4', 'avi', 'mkv'];     

$filepaths = [];

foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $current = $filename . '.' . $extension;

    if (!file_exists($current)) {
        continue;
    }

    $filepaths[] = $current;
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php